# Jar containing 80 balls. 40 red and 40 black.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The jar contains 80 balls. 40 are red and 40 are black. We pick 20 balls out of the jar without putting them back. What is the probability that 10 out of 20 balls will be black and the other 10 will be red. 
I tried to solve with binomial coefficients by counting favorable outcomes but failed to do that. I also know that the answer is $0.2$ but I'm interested in the solution.

Comment: Please show us what you attempted.

Comment: The answer is only approximately $0.2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select 10 out of 40 AND 10 out of 40, there are $(\binom{40}{10})^2$ ways to do it and he total number of ways to select 20 out of 80 is  $\binom{80}{20}$

Answer (score 1):

There are $40 \choose 10$ ways to pick red balls.
There are $40 \choose 10$ ways to pick black balls.
The total possible ways to pick balls are $80 \choose20$. 
Thus the probability is:

$$P(10, 10) = \frac{\binom{40}{10}\binom{40}{10}}{\binom{80}{20}}$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.